# Failed to find style 'My_Button' in current theme when I set style attribute programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, button, styles

I'm trying to create my own button based on `android.widget.Button`. But when I set style attribute programmatically, I'm getting this Rendering Problem:

> Failed to find style 'My_Button' in current theme

However set style in xml is work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0B5H.png)

Am I missing something?

---

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<com.myapp.Components.Button
    android:id="@+id/xx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="touch_"
    app:_icon=""/>
<com.myapp.Components.Button
    style="@style/My_Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="touch"
    app:_icon=""/>
```

---

**Button.java**

```java
public class Button extends android.widget.Button {
    public Button(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context, null, R.style.My_Button);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public Button(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.style.My_Button);
        init(context, attrs);
    }
    public Button(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, R.style.My_Button);
        init(context, attrs);
    }
    // ... more
}
```

---

**styles.xml**

```xml
<style name="My_Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:foreground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:background">#592612</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the answer!

Replace:

`super(context, attrs, R.style.My_Button);` with `super(context, attrs, R.attr.ButtonStyle);`

In **styles.xml** add

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="ButtonStyle">@style/Button_Style</item>
    ...
</style>
```

---

In **attrs.xml** add

```
<declare-styleable name="Theme">
    <attr name="ButtonStyle" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```